# Python tkinter error when changing menu label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change a cascade label on a tkinter `tk.Tk()` menu but I am getting the error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-label"
```

To trigger the error you have to press "`File`" and then "`Change`"

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.cascade = tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=self.cascade)
        self.cascade.add_command(label="Change",command=self.change_cascade_label)

    def change_cascade_label(self):
        self.menubar.entryconfig(0,label="Edit")

run = app()
run.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the 0 to a 1 in the `self.menubar.entryconfig` line. The first parameter 1 has to be the index of the item you want to change, starting from 1.

Comment: `self.menubar.entryconfig(1,label="Edit")`

Comment: @Nae thanks for contributing the code. I probably should have put that in my answer.